# Cassandra does not support DELETE on indexed columns

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

Say I have a cassandra table xyz with the following schema :

```
create table xyz(
xyzid uuid,
name text,
fileid int, 
sid    int,
PRIMARY KEY(xyzid));
```

I create index on columns fileid , sid:

```
CREATE INDEX file_index ON xyz (fileid);
CREATE INDEX sid_index ON xyz (sid);
```

I insert data :

```
INSERT INTO xyz (xyzid, name , fileid , sid ) VALUES ( now(), 'p120' , 1, 100);
INSERT INTO xyz (xyzid, name , fileid , ssid ) VALUES ( now(), 'p120' , 1, 101);
INSERT INTO xyz (xyzid, name , fileid , sid ) VALUES ( now(), 'p122' , 2, 101);
```

I want to delete data using the indexed columns :

```
 DELETE from xyz WHERE fileid=1 and sid=101;
```

Why do I get this error ?

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Non PRIMARY KEY fileid found in where clause"
```

1. Is it mandatory to specify the primary key in the where clause for delete queries ?
2. Does Cassandra supports deletes using secondary index s ?
3. What has to be done to delete data using secondary index s ?
4. Any suggestions that could help .

I am using Data Stax Community Cassandra 2.1.8 but I also want to know whether delete using indexed columns is supported by Data Stax Community Cassandra 3.2.1

Thanks

Comment: How often are you really querying only by PRIMARY KEY?  If those indexes are so important for you to have, why don't you create a query table that uses those indexed columns as PRIMARY KEY components?

Answer (score 3):

Let me try and answer your questions in order:

1) Yes, if you are going to use a where clause in a CQL statement then the PARTITION KEY must be an equality operator in the where clause.  Other than that you are only allowed to filter on clustering columns specified in your primary key. (Unless you have a secondary index)

2) No it does not.  See this post for some more information as it is essentially the same problem.
[Why can cassandra "select" on secondary key, but not update using secondary key? (1.2.8+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162070/why-can-cassandra-select-on-secondary-key-but-not-update-using-secondary-key)

3) Why not add `sid` as a clustering column in your primary key.  This would allow you to do the delete or query using both as you have shown.

`create table xyz(
xyzid uuid,
name text,
fileid int, 
sid    int,
PRIMARY KEY(xyzid, sid));`

4) In general using secondary indexes is considered an anti-pattern (a bit less so with SASI indexes in C* 3.4) so my question is can you add these fields as clustering columns to your primary key?  How are you querying these secondary indexes?

Comment: Plus 1 from me.  I like your answer to #4...can't emphasize that enough.  Too many people treat Cassandra like a relational database, and then wonder why it doesn't work like they thought it would.

Comment: @bechbd : Even if I keep the "sid" field as clustering column . And fire a query DELETE from xyz where sid = 101 . It would end up with this error : "Some partition key parts are missing: xyzid" .  One Sid would define a particular set of data in the table. I basically want to fire a query which would delete all the data having the sid I mention in the where clause . If I would have to specify the "xyzid" along with "sid" to delete that particular set of data belonging to a "sid" how would I do that ? For me xyzid is nothing but it makes each row unique . What would you suggest ?

Comment: In CQL you always have to include the entire PARTITION KEY in the where clause including while deleting.  So from what your stating here ``` One Sid would define a particular set of data in the table``` this would lead me to say that you should be using the `sid` field as the PARTITION KEY in your table not xyzid.

Comment: But If I have sid as PARTITION KEY , how will every row be unique ? Say I have 10 rows with sid 100 ? It will get overridden right if I keep sid as a PARTITION KEY ?

Comment: You would use something like a PRIMARY KEY (sid, xyzid).  This would make you able to find an individual row for updates etc by `WHERE sid=A AND xyzid=B` and also allow you to delete an entire sid by `WHERE sid=A`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can perform delete in two steps:

1. Select data by secondary index and get primary index column values
   (xyzid) from query result
2. Perform delete by primary index values.