# can we use >,<,>=,<=,like in update query for cassandra db

Tags: cassandra

I can use only = and IN in the update query for Cassandra Data Base.When i am using <,> or like,it is giving error.But for select statements,it is working.can any one tell ,how to use those operator in update query..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use inequalities in update statements. Cassandra requires you to specify a full primary key when updating a row. Performing a write using inequalities is outside the scope of Cassandra's write path, as it would require Cassandra to perform a read before writing the data - which goes against being optimised for writes.

Zanson has written up a good answer covering this to a similar question here: [Why can cassandra "select" on secondary key, but not update using secondary key? (1.2.8+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162070/why-can-cassandra-select-on-secondary-key-but-not-update-using-secondary-key)